# My TextBox added programmatically in code behind After Page reload losess values. Is there any way to work around this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Like on the subject I have a problem with creating a textBox by an Event on Button then I lost values in textbox after reload.
My code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["numberOfCountry"] = null;
    }
}

protected void BtnAddAnotherCountry(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    Session["numberOfCountry"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["numberOfCountry"]) + i;
}

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(Session["numberOfCountry"]); i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "CountryNext" + i;
        pnlAnotherTxtbox.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Any proposition? I try also create my loop in Page Load but it creates my textbox after second reload the page because First Event is Page Reload then Button.

Comment: How you are trying to get the Textbox value can you show that one

Comment: You'd be losing value because you recreate the textbox on reload surely and it doesnt try to populate the value on creation from the session variables

Comment: When i do this on Postback im not losing my values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is everyone always fooling around in `OnPreRender`, `Page_Init`, `OnPreLoad` when it comes to Dynamic controls. That is not needed at all.

Just add them in `Page_load` and their values will be retained.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(Session["numberOfCountry"]); i++)
        {
            addControl(i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Session["numberOfCountry"] = "0";
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["numberOfCountry"]) + 1;
    Session["numberOfCountry"] = i;
    addControl(i);
}

private void addControl(int index)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "CountryNext" + index;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```

Comment: I said that when i do it in page load it works on second load. Because first load is `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` then `Button Event` so it wont works well..

Comment: You want 1 textbox at the start of the page before the first PostBack?

Comment: No i want to add textbox after Button click

Comment: Updated my answer. That is how you should add dynamic controls.

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Now you are adding your textbox's to panel so you have to loop through the panel control

```
foreach ( Control panel in this.dummypanel) {
    foreach ( Control ctrl in panel) {
        // etc..
       string txt = ctrl.Text; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand it where i have to place it? this loop saves my values of textboxes?

Comment: Yeah because you are adding your text box control to panel and one more thing until and unless you clear the panel the textbox value will be present. you can place this code where you want to get the textbox value.

Comment: `foreach ( Control panel in this.dummypanel) ` dont work in my code it sais that it dont contains _Enumerator_